# reshaping data with non unique replicate variables

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I've searched and searched but I'm stuck on what I'm sure isn't a difficult problem, I just can't for the life of me figure it out.

I have a very large QPCR data frame with an output similar to the example below, except with many more patients and more Detector genes. I need to cast into a wide format so that patient 1 (P1) has there corresponding detector and ct values in the same row.

```
Sample  Detector  Ct 
P1      18s       9.428771 
P1      18s       9.369728
P1      18s       9.456004
P1      b2m       12.792814
P1      b2m       12.580547
P1      b2m       13.162326
P2      18s       19.428771 
P2      18s       19.369728
P2      18s       19.456004
P2      b2m       20.792814
P2      b2m       20.580547
P2      b2m       20.162326
```

I can cast the 1st replicate only using the following:

```
reshape(data, direction = "wide", idvar='Sample', timevar='Detector')
```

But can't cast the replicate values as they have the same name as the 1st.

I've tried `make.names` but can't get it to uniquely name the Detector based upon the value of Detector and Sample.

Any help would be gratefully received.

EDIT:

Martin asked how I would like the data to look, below is an example. I've renamed the column names for my genes as I understand this is how R would need them to be in order to deal with the data.  *Thank you Martin for sorting out the formatting for me too*.

```
Sample  X18s       X18s.1     X18S.2     b2m        b2m.1      b2m.2
P1      9.428771   9.369728   9.456004   12.792814  12.580547  13.162326      
P2      19.428771  19.369728  19.456004  20.792814  20.580547  20.162326
```

Comment: How would you like the output to look like? I can't tell from the data, because I encounter the same problem as R does, what to do with multiple observations for the same detector?

Comment: A very good question! I've edited my main post at the bottom to help.

Comment: @James. I. I updated the commands. Please check if that helps.

Comment: That's done it thank you. Works perfectly scaled up on my 306 patient by 34 genes result list too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
 data$indx <-with(data, ave(Sample, Detector, Sample, FUN=seq_along))
 reshape(data, direction="wide", idvar=c("Sample","indx"), timevar="Detector")[,-2]
 #  Sample    Ct.18s   Ct.b2m
 #1     P1  9.428771 12.79281
 #2     P1  9.369728 12.58055
 #3     P1  9.456004 13.16233
 #7     P2 19.428771 20.79281
 #8     P2 19.369728 20.58055
 #9     P2 19.456004 20.16233
```

#### Update

You could try:

```
    library(reshape2)
    dcast(data, Sample~Detector+indx, value.var="Ct")
    Sample     18s_1     18s_2     18s_3    b2m_1    b2m_2    b2m_3
 #1     P1  9.428771  9.369728  9.456004 12.79281 12.58055 13.16233
 #2     P2 19.428771 19.369728 19.456004 20.79281 20.58055 20.16233
```

Other option is to use `dplyr`

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  data%>%
  unite(Det,Detector, indx,sep=".")%>%
  spread(Det,Ct)
  #  Sample     18s.1     18s.2     18s.3    b2m.1    b2m.2    b2m.3
  #1     P1  9.428771  9.369728  9.456004 12.79281 12.58055 13.16233
  #2     P2 19.428771 19.369728 19.456004 20.79281 20.58055 20.16233
```

#### Update

I used `stringsAsFactors=F` while reading the data, so that the character columns won't get coerced to factor.  If I use `stringsAsFactors=T` or the default, then:

```
    data$indx <-with(data, ave(Sample, Detector, Sample, FUN=seq_along))
    #Warning messages:
   #1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:3) :
    invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Replace the above step with:

```
    data$indx <-with(data, ave(seq_along(Sample), Detector, Sample, FUN=seq_along))
    dcast(data, Sample~Detector+indx, value.var="Ct")
   #  Sample     18s_1     18s_2     18s_3    b2m_1    b2m_2    b2m_3
   #1     P1  9.428771  9.369728  9.456004 12.79281 12.58055 13.16233
   #2     P2 19.428771 19.369728 19.456004 20.79281 20.58055 20.16233
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, I apologise for not being clearer in my first question. I've placed a table of how I would like the data to look after the reshape into the question now. I think the key is renaming my Detector values as detector,detector.1,detector.2 before I try the reshape but I can't figure that out either.

Comment: Thanks Akrun, that's exactly what I want to see. I'm afraid my grasp of the commands `with,ave,seq_along` isn't good enough to deal with the error I get when I use your code on my data. I get 'more than 50 warnings' which are all along the lines of In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:3) : invalid factor level, NA generated'

Comment: @James I. Could you show an example dataset (preferably using `dput(head(data, 20))` that shows the error you mentioned.  Also, try `with(data, ave(1:nrow(data), Detector, Sample, FUN=seq_along))` in place of the 1st command.  I am assuming that you get error in this step.  I used sample as character column

Comment: Akrun you've nailed it! The final solution works flawlessly. Thank you so much! I had a hideously complicated loop doing this function and knew that reshape2 had the potential to be less code and less chance of unknowingly mixing my data up. I just couldn't solve the puzzle sorting puzzle. Once again thank you!